# Is it possible to save a group of files with MinIO client in one transaction?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, transactions, inputstream, minio

I have a Spring Boot application which stores files on a MinIO server. My application receives groups of files and should save all files per each group or save nothing in a problem group. I use `io.minio.MinioClient#putObject` for each file in a group. Now my code looks like

```
fun saveFile(folderName: String, fileName: String, file: ByteArray) {
    file.inputStream().use {
        minioClient.putObject(folderName, fileName, it, PutObjectOptions(file.size.toLong(), -1))
    }
}

fun saveFiles(folderName: String, files: Map<String, ByteArray>) {
    try {
        files.forEach { (fileName, file) -> saveFile(folderName, fileName, file) }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        files.forEach { (fileName, _) -> minioClient.removeObject(folderName, fileName) }
        throw e
    }
}
```

I wonder how I could refactor my `saveFiles` method to make it more transactional.

N.B. There are no rules about reading files by groups - each file could be read individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use this S3 [feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/developer-guide/batching-small-files.html), [MinIO](https://blog.min.io/minio-optimizes-small-objects/) also support this feature.

Create .tar or .zip archive and send to S3 with metadata option `snowball-auto-extract=true` (header: `X-Amz-Meta-Snowball-Auto-Extract`), archive will be automatically extracted in S3.

This is not transaction but look very similar for me.